# vim highlighting to right edge of screen

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

Is it possible to define a syntax group where highlighting would extend to the right edge of the screen (and not just to the last character in the line) ? This group could potentially match several lines. I am not trying to highlight the current cursor line, but rather whole comment blocks.

Answer (score -1):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524380/vim-left-and-right-column-highlight)

You may be able to use:

```
:match DiffAdd '\%>72v.*'
```